# Edit .NL files to reformulate problem instances

Tags: python, pyomo

I would like to run a solvers comparison on several instances of MINLPLib. I can get the .NL files for each instance. Now, I would like to reformulate several instances and I need to edit the .NL files (in particular I would like to add a term to the objective function). I would ask you if you know an easy way to read and modify directly the .NL files for instance using Pyomo via Python.

Comment: That may not be so easy. I would take one of the source files (.mod, .gms) and go from there. If you really desperately need Pyomo files, GAMS/Convert can translate the .gms file to a Pyomo file.

Answer (score 5):

It is basically impossible to edit a .nl file by hand correctly (unless it's a trivially simple file), since information about what's happening is distributed across the file in very non-obvious, partially undocumented, and order-dependent ways.

One way you could do this in practice is to use the [Octeract Reformulator API](https://github.com/Octeract/reformulator) (it's free) to import the .nl file, modify what you want, and write to a new .nl file:

```py
from octeract import *

model = Model()
model.import_model_file("/home/nikos/octeract/engine/test-libraries/stability_tests/ex6_1_1.nl")
print(model)
obj = model.get_objective_function_string()
model.minimize(obj+"+sin(x1*x2)")
print(model)
model.write_problem_to_NL_file("myNewProblem.nl")
```

Comment: Wow the reformulator is very cool! Agree that working with nl files by hand is ... difficult.